# Can I enter Swaziland if I have a 5-year ban from South Africa?

Tags: visas

Last year I was banned from entering South Africa because I had overstayed by a couple of hours (my flight was delayed by a day, which meant I could not leave the country, forcing me to overstay). When I explained this to the immigration officials they would not listen to my side of the story and they gave me a 2-year ban.

Can I still enter Swaziland? Or does the ban extend to Swaziland?

Comment: I have edited your question (words missing, improper capitalization), but there is still a discrepancy between your title (5 year) and text (2 year). Please [edit] and spend some more time on checking your next question before you post it.

Comment: Swaziland and South Africa are independent countries, why would a ban by South Africa have any effect in Swaziland...? So long as you don't intend to enter via South Africa you should be fine.

Comment: It appears the only commercial flights into Swaziland are from Johannesberg. The issue will be transfer between flights. Unless you enter by land from Mozambique.

Answer (score 3):

A ban from South Africa would not affect travel to Swaziland, a separate country with its own visa and entry regulations.

You would not be able to travel to land-locked Swaziland via South Africa. Application to South Africa for a transit visa would likely be refused and, while travellers can transit without visa in certain South African airports, those transiting have their biometric captured which would reveal your ban.

Comment: How would OP get to Swaziland without going through South Africa?

Comment: @JonathanReez well, via Mozanbique land border; there are flights to Maputo which do not connect in ZA.

Comment: @JonathanReez: Lesotho is the country which is completely surrounded by South Africa.  As Giorgio points out, Swaziland is not completely "ZA-locked".